# Why is PQexecPrepared stack smashing? C - Postgresql

Tags: c, postgresql, pointers, stack, dynamic-memory-allocation

I have a fairly complex, multithreaded application. PostgreSQL has been working wonderfully, until I switched from PQexec to using prepared statements. Behavior has been erratic, with lots of stack smashing. Here, I have condensed the main function into a very short application which returns quickly, yet I am still getting stack smashing, mostly error codes 134 and 255. I could swear that this same application worked before (I had most of the db functions abstracted into custom functions), yet when I am trying it again, it is now not working.

Please help!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <libpq-fe.h>
...

PGconn *psqldb;

int main()
{

psqldb = PQconnectdb("user=USERNAME password=PASSWORD dbname=DBNAME");
PQprepare(psqldb, "CreateUser", "INSERT into \"User\" (UserID, Email, PasswordHash, Salt, UserName) VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5)", 5, NULL);

const char *vals[5];
vals[0]="ccc";
vals[1]="aaa";
vals[2]="rrr";
vals[3]="ttt";
vals[4]="jjj";

int len[5];

len[0]=3;
len[1]=3;
len[2]=3;
len[3]=3;
len[4]=3;


PGresult *res = PQexecPrepared(psqldb,
                               "CreateUser",
                               5,
                               vals,
                               len,
                               NULL,
                               0);


if (PQresultStatus(res) != PGRES_COMMAND_OK) {
    fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", PQerrorMessage(psqldb));
    PQclear(res);
    PQfinish(psqldb);

    return -1;
}
PQclear(res);

fprintf(stderr, "returning\n");
PQfinish(psqldb);

return 0;
}
```

It actually does insert the data into the db, because I am getting a unique key constraint error when I run it multiple times

```
ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "User_pkey"
DETAIL:  Key (userid)=(ccc) already exists.


Process finished with exit code 255
```

and in the terminal I get

```
*** stack smashing detected ***
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried replacing the len[] array by a NULL in the function call (it is not needed for strings, but *shouldnot* cause harm) Or maybe replace the 3s  by 4s (including the '\0' in the length seems fair for strings)

Comment: replacing len with NULL does the same thing.     Also, I have noticed that if I declare some stack array immediately after executing the prepared statement, say, char query[1024], it seems to work. I am very frustrated

Comment: also, replacing len with 4 instead of 3 still smashes the stack.

Comment: {Versions, compilerflags, optimisation, ...} maybe add more canaries or even move all of your variables to global scope.

Comment: using clang -Wall -O3

Comment: You could try to use `PGconn *PQconnectdbParams(const char * const *keywords, const char * const *values, int expand_dbname);` instead of your pqconnctdb(). It has separate parameters fo user/passwd/database/host. [Plus: maybe the ABI for the library is different from what you expect]